# Installed rails with RubyGems but ran my first rails new blog command with errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

rails -v
ruby -v
gem -v

all get proper answers.
But when I run
rails new blog,
I get the following error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError)
```

Below is the full trace:

```
run  bundle install
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/https.rb:92:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:447:in `ssl'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:216:in `connection_for'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:358:in `request'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:135:in `fetch'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:163:in `fetch_dependency_remote_specs'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:122:in `fetch_remote_specs'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:70:in `specs'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:234:in `block in remote_specs'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `remote_specs'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:165:in `fetch_specs'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:70:in `specs'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:205:in `block (2 levels) in index'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:202:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:202:in `block in index'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:198:in `index'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `resolve'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:122:in `resolve_remotely!'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:48:in `run'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:12:in `install'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220:in `install'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/bin/bundle:13:in
```

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `rails -v`, `ruby -v` and `gem -v`

Comment: ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux]

 gem -v
1.8.21    rails -v
Rails 3.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try installing libopenssl-ruby package.

```
sudo apt-get install libopenssl-ruby
```

You have to reinstall ruby after this.

Comment: I installed the libopenssl-ruby and reinstalled the ruby, but the error still exists

Comment: How did you installed ruby ? If you've installed with rvm and/or rbenv, you'll have to recompile/reinstall it with libssl-dev installed.

Comment: Well,I think your answer is correct. I previously did not uninstall ruby clearly....

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install openssl libssl-dev` - libssl-dev adds the development headers.